# Cleanest way to initialize a session variable in a servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, session, servlets

What would be a clean and neat way to initialize a session variable in a servlet, considering session variables are not inherently thread-safe?

Consider the following code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // NOT thread safe
    if( request.getSession().getAttribute("mySessionVariable") == null )
        request.getSession().setAttribute("mySessionVariable", new AtomicInteger(0));

    ((AtomicInteger) request.getSession().getAttribute("mySessionVariable")).incrementAndGet();

}
```

In the above code, there is a chance that two threads will concurrently see that the variable is null, and therefor both initialize it to 0. To avoid this, of course one could use a synchronized block:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    synchronized(this){
        if( request.getSession().getAttribute("mySessionVariable") == null )
            request.getSession().setAttribute("mySessionVariable", new AtomicInteger(0));

        ((AtomicInteger) request.getSession().getAttribute("mySessionVariable")).incrementAndGet();
    }

}
```

But I'm wondering, are there any cleaner and "prettier" ways of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

When the user Session is created, you could add the `mySessionVariable` attribute in the session :

```
 session.setAttribute("mySessionVariable", new AtomicInteger(0));
```

If you don't handle explicitly the creation of the Session in a servlet, you can do the initialization with `HttpSessionListener` in the `public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0)` method.

So, this code becomes thread safe since you don't need to initialize the attribute any longer and `AtomicInteger` sets atomically the `int` value,  :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{ 

   ((AtomicInteger)request.getSession().getAttribute("mySessionVariable")).incrementAndGet();

}
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but for some reason I can't make it work - see my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082885/httpsessionlistener-sessioncreated-not-being-called).